# Windows 10 Apps Dissapear from Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

I recently "upgraded" to Windows 10. I have been pretty happy with my experience, but about a month after upgrading, all the apps I installed from the Store disappeared from the Start menu. All the desktop software I installed not from the store still shows up fine. I was able to use the search / Cortana to find the apps, and in the search results it said "install" and when I clicked the result, it showed up in the Store as already installed and the button read "open". I did an in place upgrade two days ago, and the problem has already shown up again after almost 2 days of working fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A possible work-around: third-party Start Menu replacements such as Classic Shell usually survive MS updates better than its own Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the possible causes of updates as the updated apps icons were deleted and not recreated in the start menu. I believe that this has nothing to do with your current system configuration but with the app developers themselves.

As you can search for the app you can also `Pin to Start`. Simply locate the needed app, right click on it and choose `Pin to Start` option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not currently able to pin the apps from the start menu search bar. The only option is to install them from the store even though I already have.

Comment: @MatthewFegan Have you previously installed those apps under Microsoft account? Are you logged in with the same account as previously?

Comment: Yes, I am logged into Windows 10 with the same Microsoft account I used to install the apps.